# Initialize multiple attributes at initialization from a single attribute

Tags: python-3.x

I have a class as such:

```py
class Line:
    def __init__(self, text: str):
        self.text = text
```

A line in my case can have many `features`. For example,

1. The line is considered long if it has more than 50 characters.
2. If the line has non-ascii characters, then a flag is set as non_ascii = True
   and so on
3. Find all the urls in the line

I am able to implement them in terms of class methods:

```py
class Line:
    def __init__(self, text: str):
        self.text = text

    def is_ascii(self):
        # check and return
    
    def is_long(self):
        # check and return

    def urls(self):
        # find and return urls
```

The problem I have is, I need to make the method calls on the Line object multiple times at different stages in the process (some of the method calls are pretty computationally heavy).

What I would like to have is, at initialization, I would like the Line object to have attributes such as is_ascii, is_long, urls to be pre populated so that they can be accessed multiple times without the need to compute them every time they are accessed.

```py
class Line:
    def __init__(self, text: str):
        self.text = text
        self.is_ascii = do some processing on self.text, and assign value
        self.is_long = do some processing on self.text, and assign value
        self.urls = do some processing on self.text, and assign value
```

I am not sure if having all that logic live inside the **init** block makes sense. How would I achieve this in a 'pythonic' manner?

Comment: @Carcigenicate: thanks for the reply. If it is possible, can you please show how the caching would work? I am not very well versed in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just have the methods that you do, and call them from within `__init__`:

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, text: str):
        self.text = text
        self.is_ascii = self.calc_is_ascii(self.text)
        self.is_long = self.calc_is_long(self.text)
        self.urls = self.calc_urls(self.text)

    def calc_is_ascii(self):
        # check and return

    def calc_is_long(self):
        # check and return

    def calc_urls(self):
        # find and return urls
```

You could also have it so if a method is called, it checks to see if the value has already been calculated, and uses the cached value, otherwise it calculates and caches it:

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, text: str):
        self.text = text
        self.is_ascii = None
        self.is_long = None
        self.urls = None

    def calc_is_ascii(self):
        if self.is_ascii is None:
            # Do expensive calculation of self.is_ascii
            self.is_ascii = expensive_result
        
        # Use the cached, previously calculated value
        return self.is_ascii

    # Then the same pattern for other methods
```

This has the benefit that if one of the attributes is never needed, the work to calculate it isn't done.

I'm initializing the attributes to `None`. If they're `None` later, I know they haven't been calculated yet. If they aren't `None`, I know they have already been calculated, so I can just return the calculated result. This of course assumes that `None` is not a valid value.